# Avoiding indentation in “parcolumns”

Tags: parcolumns

The package `parcolumns` has an option `nofirstindent` to “suppress the indentation of the first paragraph in the environment,” but apparently it indents other paragraphs, even ignoring `\noindent`.

Is there a way to avoid this, and suppressing all indentation?

Comment: The `parskip` package? If you suppress indentation, You must have a non-zero parskip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it zero with

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

I have used this inside a group so that this is effective only inside `parcolumns`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]
{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \begin{parcolumns}{2}
            \colchunk{%
                \kant[1-2]
            }
            \colchunk{%
                \kant[3-4]
            }
            \colplacechunks
        \end{parcolumns}
}
\kant[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, it works just fine!